# Flutter / Inject.dart - Is it possible to simplify or generate code for a 'provided' class instantiation?

Tags: flutter, dependency-injection, service-locator, flutter-provider

Been doing some research on Flutter Dependency Injection,and I kinda settled on Inject.dart

However, I am having some trouble using inject.

Is there any way to simplify instantitation of a injected class?

I have this MyClass, which I need to instantiate passing a HomeStore, however, how can I instatiate it without calling global acessors? (such as the ones made on the Injector file).

It seems I could just use the Get_It package otherwise, which would get me the same results, and without code generation, but I don't quite like the whole global access thing.

My sample:

```
// current code
class MyClass(){
    store = HomeStore(AppInjector().globalHudStore, AppInjector().globalErrorStore);
}
```

```
// desired code
class MyClass(){
    @instance ?
    store = HomeStore();

    store = HomeStore.instanciate?();
}
```

```
class HomeStore {
  @provide
  HomeStore(this._globalHudStore, this._globalErrorStore);

  final GlobalHudStore _globalHudStore;
  final ErrorStore _globalErrorStore;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are willing to work with json, you might want to consider this package `json_serializable`. Just search for it at `pub.dev`.

I can give a little example. Let's say you have a `User` class/model.

```
part 'user.g.dart';

@JsonSerializable()
class User {
  int id;
  @JsonKey(name: 'user_type_id')
  int userTypeId;
  String email;

  @JsonKey(name: 'user_detail')
  UserDetail userDetail;
  @JsonKey(name: 'user_type')
  UserType userType;
  @JsonKey(name: 'user_location')
  UserLocation userLocation;

  User();

  factory User.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$UserFromJson(json);

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$UserToJson(this);
}
```

and you fetched a `User` data via API, and want to create a `User` variable and fill it with data without having to do that manually.

You can actually do that with just this line of code

```
User user = User.fromJson(jsonUser);
```

These even automatically json serializes classes in your `User` class, as long as those classes are also json serializable, which is defined with `@JsonSerializable()`

So even with just that single line of code, if the `jsonUser` which came from the API also has values for `UserDetail`, `UserType`, and `UserLocation`, you can also access them.

Comment: I need dependency injection and global singleton acess to these stores (MobX), which control when to show a loading widget overlay, or send error snackbars on my app.